# Run a function after an Ajax call has completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, deferred

There is something happening that I don't know why is it happening. I have this 3 functions:

```
app.progress();
app.success();
app.normal();
```

All three change a status block in my application. And I have this `$.post` in one of my other functions, let's say:

```
app.set : function() {
  ...
}
```

In my `set` function I want to update the status block like this:

```
app.set : function() {
    app.progress();
    $.post('ajax.php', function(){
        // do stuffs
    }).done({function(){
        app.success();
        setTimeout(app.normal(), '2000');
    })
}
```

But somehow, I cannot see the `app.success`, it skips to `app.normal`, when I remove the `app.normal` I can see the `app.success`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `app.normal` right away, as that is what happens when you add the parenthesis to a function, change this:

```
setTimeout(app.normal(), '2000');
```

to

```
setTimeout(app.normal, 2000);
```

referencing the function instead of calling it.